# How can I set the value of a variable?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have found this example to set the value of a Class property:

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
string value = "5.5";
var property = ship.GetType().GetProperty("Latitude");
var convertedValue = property.Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
property.SetValue(self, convertedValue);
```

But I want to set value of a variable in my "this".

i.e. in my main form I have a private double "Momentum"

```
string value = "5.5";
var property = this.GetType().GetProperty("Momentum");
var convertedValue = property.Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
property.SetValue(self, convertedValue);
```

This does NOT work - "property" is null.

How do I alter the above code to achieve this?

Comment: `this.Momentum = 5.5` - ie, why are you using reflection in the first place?

Comment: Private double what? Field or property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously, why are you using reflection if you need to set the field value from a variable you own?

Okay, let's forget that... If you have a field and not a property, you need to use `GetField`:

```
var value = "5.5";
var field = this.GetType().GetField(nameof(Momentum), BindingFlags.NonPublic);
field.SetValue(self /* or this */, value);
```

Also, this might be a good place to use `nameof`, but that is just a suggestion.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Mom: " + Momentum);  
            var field = this.GetType().GetField("Momentum");  
            field.SetValue(field, "5.5");  
            Console.WriteLine("Mom: " + Momentum);  ` Is not working?

Comment: Sorry, it seemed a double to me, could be a string too. If you use the right type, it is okay.

Comment: my "field" is null. <br/>  the this.GetType().GetField("Momentum") is not working

Comment: Assuming the field is private. You need to add a `BindingFlag`. See my updated answer.